# yum update issue in Centos 7 likely Dependency issue

Tags: linux, mysql, yum, centos-7, dependencies

When I try to run the yum update in CentOS 7 it falls with the error. Yesterday I tried to install the MariaDB over the MySql. Currently MySql is also not starting and it shows that the MySql is not installed. And also when I check the MySql version it is showing as

`# rpm -qa | grep MySQL
compat-MySQL50-shared-5.0.96-4.cp1136.x86_64
compat-MySQL51-shared-5.1.73-1.cp1150.x86_64
MySQL56-shared-5.6.31-2.cp1156.x86_64
cpanel-perl-522-MySQL-Diff-0.43-1.cp1156.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-5.el7.x86_64`

I don't have any idea about this

When I run `yum update` the response codes I got were as follows

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, tsflags, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 185.53.12.144
 * base: mirror.yourwebhoster.eu
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * remi-safe: remi.mirrors.cu.be
 * updates: mirror.1000mbps.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-shared.x86_64 0:10.0.26-1.el7.centos will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-shared-10.0.26-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:6-8 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: epel-release = 6 for package: remi-release-6.8-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-6 will be an update
---> Package flite.x86_64 0:1.3-22.el7 will be updated
---> Package flite.x86_64 0:1.3-24.el6 will be an update
---> Package jansson.x86_64 0:2.4-6.el7 will be updated
---> Package jansson.x86_64 0:2.6-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package lcms2.x86_64 0:2.6-2.el7 will be updated
---> Package lcms2.x86_64 0:2.7-3.el6 will be an update
---> Package libdwarf.x86_64 0:20130207-4.el7 will be updated
---> Package libdwarf.x86_64 0:20140413-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package libsrtp.x86_64 0:1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsrtp.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package libsrtp.x86_64 0:1.5.4-3.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.2.3-4.el7 will be updated
---> Package libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.2.3-4.el7 will be updated
---> Package libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs for package: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: webkitgtk3-2.4.9-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: ea-php70-php-gd-7.0.9-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 will be an update
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 will be obsoleted
---> Package nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: tigervnc-server-minimal-1.3.1-4.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package nux-dextop-release.noarch 0:0-1.el7.nux will be updated
---> Package nux-dextop-release.noarch 0:0-5.el7.nux will be an update
---> Package opus.x86_64 0:1.0.2-6.el7 will be updated
---> Package opus.x86_64 0:1.1.2-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.0.1-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package qrencode-libs.x86_64 0:3.4.1-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package qrencode-libs.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package soundtouch.x86_64 0:1.4.0-9.el7 will be updated
---> Package soundtouch.x86_64 0:1.5.0-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wqy-microhei-fonts.noarch 0:0.2.0-0.12.beta.el7 will be updated
---> Package wqy-microhei-fonts.noarch 0:0.2.0-0.14.beta.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.0.26-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:6-8 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: epel-release = 6 for package: remi-release-6.8-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package libsrtp.x86_64 0:1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsrtp.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package libstoragemgmt-python-clibs.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: webkitgtk3-2.4.9-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: ea-php70-php-gd-7.0.9-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64
---> Package nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: tigervnc-server-minimal-1.3.1-4.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libconfig.so.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: remi-release-6.8-1.el6.remi.noarch (installed)
           Requires: epel-release = 6
           Removing: epel-release-6-8.noarch (installed)
               epel-release = 6-8
           Updated By: epel-release-7-6.noarch (extras)
               epel-release = 7-6
           Available: epel-release-7-5.noarch (extras)
               epel-release = 7-5
Error: Package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.4.5-3.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libsrtp.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libsrtp.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: libsrtp-1.5.4-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libsrtp.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ea-php70-php-gd-7.0.9-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64 (@EA4)
           Requires: libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: libwebp-0.3.0-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: tigervnc-server-minimal-1.3.1-4.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-38.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               python(abi) = 3.3
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-38.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               python(abi) = 3.3
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: webkitgtk3-2.4.9-5.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: libwebp-0.3.0-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gnutls-3.3.8-14.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please provide a solutions for this.

This is very urgent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also getting another error when taking mysql database in cpanel like             _Error while connecting to MySQL: (XID sz44qn) Database Connect Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Error while connecting to MySQL: (XID sz44qn) Database Connect Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mysql.pm line 173. _

Comment: What did you do when you tried to install MariaDB?